# Why can't I compile with the -dynamic option?

Tags: haskell, haskell-stack

I am very much beginning with Haskell and, following a video, I tried the following:

```
stack ghc -- -dynamic test.hs
```

The following error message was generated:

```
test.hs:1:1: error:
    Failed to load interface for `Prelude'
    Perhaps you haven't installed the "dyn" libraries for package `base-4.9.1.0'?
    Use -v to see a list of the files searched for.
```

I tried to use -v as suggested but that did not help.

A similar command without -dynamic works fine but generates a much larger executable file:

```
stack ghc test.hs
```

Any suggestions on how to fix this?

(This is under Windows 10).

Answer (score 0):

Apparently, dynamic linking is not supported on Windows: https://discourse.haskell.org/t/haskell-stack-cant-compile-with-dynamic/1409.